# reactjs with typescript and ibazel not working

Tags: reactjs, npm, bazel

I looked at [this](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_nodejs/tree/stable/examples/create-react-app) example how to run/build a react app with bazel. The only difference to my project is, that the react project is in a subdirectory called 'ui'. So the WORSPACE file is not in the react directory but in the parent directory. My WORSPACE file:

```
workspace(
    name = "tool",
    managed_directories = {"@npm": ["ui:node_modules"]},
)

load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

http_archive(
    name = "build_bazel_rules_nodejs",
    sha256 = "10fffa29f687aa4d8eb6dfe8731ab5beb63811ab00981fc84a93899641fd4af1",
    urls = ["https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_nodejs/releases/download/2.0.3/rules_nodejs-2.0.3.tar.gz"],
)

http_archive(
    name = "bazel_skylib",
    sha256 = "97e70364e9249702246c0e9444bccdc4b847bed1eb03c5a3ece4f83dfe6abc44",
    urls = [
        "https://mirror.bazel.build/github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-skylib/releases/download/1.0.2/bazel-skylib-1.0.2.tar.gz",
        "https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-skylib/releases/download/1.0.2/bazel-skylib-1.0.2.tar.gz",
    ],
)

load("@build_bazel_rules_nodejs//:index.bzl", "npm_install")

npm_install(
    # Name this npm so that Bazel Label references look like @npm//package
    name = "npm",
    package_json = "//ui:package.json",
    package_lock_json = "//ui:package-lock.json",
)
```

My package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "ui",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "typescript": "~3.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@bazel/bazelisk": "^1.6.1",
    "@bazel/ibazel": "^0.13.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ibazel run //ui:start",
    "build": "bazel build //ui:build",
    "test": "ibazel test //ui:test"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Last but not least the BUILD.bazel file which is in the ui folder. I change the line `"--node_options=--require=$(rootpath chdir.js)",` in the start job to `"--node_options=--require=./$(rootpath chdir.js)",`

```
load("@bazel_skylib//rules:write_file.bzl", "write_file")
load("@build_bazel_rules_nodejs//:index.bzl", "copy_to_bin", "nodejs_test")
load("@npm//react-scripts:index.bzl", "react_scripts", "react_scripts_test")
load("@io_bazel_rules_docker//container:container.bzl", "container_image")
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/pkg:pkg.bzl", "pkg_tar")
load("@build_bazel_rules_nodejs//:index.bzl", "npm_package_bin")

# Filename conventions described at
# https://create-react-app.dev/docs/running-tests#filename-conventions
_TESTS = [
    "src/**/*.test.js*",
    "src/**/*.test.ts*",
    "src/**/*.spec.js*",
    "src/**/*.spec.ts*",
    "src/**/__tests__/**/*.js*",
    "src/**/__tests__/**/*.ts*",
]

# We don't want to teach react-scripts to include from multiple directories
# So we copy everything it wants to read to the output "bin" directory
copy_to_bin(
    name = "copy_static_files",
    srcs = glob(
        [
            "public/*",
            "src/**/*",
        ],
        exclude = _TESTS,
    ) + [
        "package.json",
        "tsconfig.json",
    ],
)

# react-scripts can only work if the working directory is the root of the application.
# So we'll need to chdir before it runs.
write_file(
    name = "write_chdir_script",
    out = "chdir.js",
    content = ["process.chdir(__dirname)"],
)

_RUNTIME_DEPS = [
    "chdir.js",
    "copy_static_files",
    "@npm//react",
    "@npm//react-dom",
]

react_scripts(
    # Note: this must be named "build" since react-scripts hard-codes that as the output dir
    name = "build",
    args = [
        "--node_options=--require=./$(execpath chdir.js)",
        "build",
    ],
    data = _RUNTIME_DEPS + [
        "@npm//@types",
    ],
    output_dir = True,
)

nodejs_test(
    name = "build_smoke_test",
    data = ["build"],
    entry_point = "build_smoke_test.js",
)

copy_to_bin(
    name = "copy_test_files",
    srcs = glob(_TESTS),
)

react_scripts_test(
    name = "test",
    args = [
        "--node_options=--require=$(rootpath chdir.js)",
        "test",
        # ibazel is the watch mode for Bazel when running tests
        # Because Bazel is really a CI system that runs locally
        "--watchAll=false",
        "--no-cache",
        "--no-watchman",
        "--ci",
    ],
    data = _RUNTIME_DEPS + [
        "copy_test_files",
        "@npm//@testing-library/dom",
        "@npm//@testing-library/jest-dom",
        "@npm//@testing-library/react",
        "@npm//@testing-library/user-event",
    ],
    # Need to set the pwd to avoid jest needing a runfiles helper
    # Windows users with permissions can use --enable_runfiles
    # to make this test work
    tags = ["no-bazelci-windows"],
)

react_scripts(
    name = "start",
    args = [
        "--node_options=--require=./$(rootpath chdir.js)",
        "start",
    ],
    data = _RUNTIME_DEPS,
)
```

Executing 'npm start' gives the following output:

```
iBazel [4:20PM]: Querying for files to watch...
Loading: 0 packages loaded
Loading: 0 packages loaded
Loading: 0 packages loaded
Loading: 204 packages loaded

Loading: 204 packages loaded
Loading: 0 packages loaded
Loading: 0 packages loaded
Loading: 0 packages loaded
Loading: 993 packages loaded

Loading: 993 packages loaded
iBazel [4:21PM]: Running //ui:start
INFO: Invocation ID: 5800c1f9-01ac-4381-9819-5bca2d305477
Loading: 
Loading: 0 packages loaded
Loading: 0 packages loaded
Loading: 0 packages loaded
Analyzing: target //ui:start (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured)
INFO: Analyzed target //ui:start (204 packages loaded, 36970 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...

INFO: Elapsed time: 17.860s
INFO: 0 processes.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 0 total actions
INFO: Build completed successfully, 0 total actions
INFO: Invocation ID: 45f00b98-1378-42de-a0f6-b0fdf2dbe33f
Loading: 
Loading: 0 packages loaded
Loading: 0 packages loaded
Loading: 0 packages loaded
Analyzing: target //ui:start (1 packages loaded, 0 targets configured)
INFO: Analyzed target //ui:start (993 packages loaded, 36792 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
[0 / 1] [Prepa] BazelWorkspaceStatusAction stable-status.txt
Target //ui:start up-to-date:
  dist/bin/ui/start.sh
  dist/bin/ui/start_loader.js
  dist/bin/ui/start_require_patch.js
INFO: Elapsed time: 20.162s, Critical Path: 0.17s
INFO: 0 processes.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action
iBazel [4:22PM]: Starting...

################################################################################
# Did you know iBazel can invoke programs like Gazelle, buildozer, and         #
# other BUILD file generators for you automatically based on bazel output?     #
# Documentation at: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-watcher#output-runner  #
################################################################################
Starting the development server...
```

Than nothing happens and it hangs.

For testing purposes I copied the workspace file into the react project and adjusted the places I changed from the example. Then 'npm start' works until `Starting the development server...` then it hangs and nothings happens. Trying the plain example project gives the same result. It hangs at `Starting the development server...`.